# Firebase function not fetching config variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write a firebase function to send a transactional e-mail with SendGrid whenever it gets triggered by a HTTP request, but at the moment I'm having real difficulty getting the function to be able to access the configuration variables that I've set with the sendgrid key which is obviously a real problem...

I've set the config variable with the below command:

```
$  firebase functions:config:set sendgrid.key="KEY_HERE"
```

When I run `firebase functions:config:get` to list all the config values, it returns the correct value in the terminal:

```
{
  "sendgrid": {
    "key": "KEY_HERE"
  }
}
```

But when I try to access it from my function (tried with both TypeScript & Vanilla JS setups), `functions.config()` just returns an empty object.

Has anyone encountered & solved this issue before, or am I doing something wrong?  In either case, if anyone could give me a pointer then that'd be much appreciated!

**Edit the first**
I have deployed the function, and called it while hosted and looking at the logs, you can see the correct values.  However, I still see the problem when I call the function when served locally on my machine for testing, which is a problem as I'd like to not have to deploy a function just to see if it works...

Comment: Did you deploy after setting the config?

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't initially but then saw the prompt on the CLI to deploy it so I did but it still shows as an empty object.

Would it be something to do with the fact that I'm running it locally for testing?  Seems a bit odd to only be able to test deployed code while you're working on it...